# I cant figure out how to make my loop work in my space invader like game in Javascript

Tags: javascript, p5.js

For my space invader like game I want to make bullets that get shot by the enemies but the problem is that the bullets dont appear in this loop that I made. I tried several things like making only one bullet appear while that works it is not the result that I want. My idea behind the code is that a new bullet gets shot from the position of the enemies when the enemybullet.position == 1 and if it exceeds the height of the canvas I want the bullet to return to the enemies and be shot again.

The code that I used for this result is here:

sketch.js

```
var enemies = []; 
var enemybullet = []; 


function setup() {

    createCanvas(800, 600);

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        enemies[i] = new Enemy(i*300+300, 100);
    } 
    
    // I tried enemybullet = new Enemybullet(120, 200); and that drew the bullet but it   wasnt assigned to the enemy

    rectMode(CENTER);

}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    // enemybullet.show(); this is wat I used to draw the single projectile
    // enemybullet.move();

    var edge = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
        enemies[i].show();
        enemies[i].move();
        if(enemies[i].x > width || enemies[i].x < 0) {
          edge = true;
        }
    }
    
    if (edge) {
        for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
          enemies[i].shiftDown();
        }
    }    
    
    for (var i = 0; i < enemybullet.length; i++) {
        enemybullet[i].show();
        enemybullet[i].move();
        for (var j = 0; j < enemies.length; j++) {
            if(enemybullet[i].position == 1){
              var enemybullets = new Enemybullet(enemies[j].x(), enemies[j].y());
              enemybullet.push(enemybullets);
              enemybullet[i].x = enemybullet[i].x;
              enemybullet[i].y = enemybullet[i].y + enemybullet[i].speed;
            

              if(enemybullet[i].y >= height){
                enemybullet[i].position = 2;
              }
            }

            else{
              enemybullet[i].y = enemies[i].y;
              enemybullet[i].x = enemies[i].x;
            }
  
            if(enemybullet[i].position == 2 ){
              enemybullet[i].y = enemies[i].y;
              enemybullet[i].x = enemies[i].x;
              enemybullet[i].position = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

enemybullet.js

```
function Enemybullet(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = 10; 
    this.height = 20; 
    this.position = 1;
    this.speed = 2;

    this.show = function() {
        fill('#ADD8E6'); 
        rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }

    this.move = function() {
        this.x = this.x;
        this.y = this.y + this.speed; 
    }

}
```

enemy.js

```
function Enemy(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = 100; 
    this.xdir = 1; 

    this.shot = function() {
        this.r = this.r * 0; 
        this.xdir = this.xdir * 0;
    }

    this.shiftDown = function() {
        this.xdir *= -1; 
        this.y += this.r/2;
    }


    this.show = function() {
        fill('#0000FF'); 
        rect(this.x, this.y, this.r, this.r); 
    }

    this.move = function() {
        this.x = this.x + this.xdir; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using some animation script or environment? (Like [p5.js](https://p5js.org)?)

Comment: Yes i am indeed making use of p5js but that is only for creating the canvas and adding images

Comment: Not entirely, p5.js also runs your game loop for you. It repeatedly calls `draw` for you (using `requestAnimationFrame` behind the scenes). That's important for people to know, because otherwise there's no indication your code will ever be run, much less run in a game loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having the bullets be in their own global array, try having the bullets be a variable in the Enemy class.
`this.bullet = new Enemybullet(this.x, this.y);`
Then you can give the enemies functions such as the following to update the bullets.

```
this.updateBullet = function() {
  this.bullet.move();
  this.bullet.show();
}

this.resetBullet = function() {
  this.bullet = new Enemybullet(this.x, this.y);
}
```

Where you were looping through each bullet before, you can instead call `enemies[i].updateBullet();` when you move and show the enemies.
And when you want the enemies to shoot another shot, call `enemies[i].resetBullet();`

You can see my implementation [here](https://editor.p5js.org/Henhen1227_/sketches/g_pOOp9Md).